# Select first child elements of multiple parent elements and apply same class to all

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm looking for a way to select the first child element of multiple parent divs,  of which the parent divs have the same class. This is my HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <p>Select this paragraph</p>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" title="Select this image">
  <p>Don't select this</p>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <p>Select this paragraph</p>
  <p>Don't select this paragraph</p>
</div>
```

Please see my full [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NLpYWj) Here.

I'm trying to select the first child element of each div with the class `wrapper` and apply the same class to all of these child elements. I was looking at something in the lines of this:

```
$('.wrapper').children(":first").addClass("noMargin");
```

The problem with this is that it only selects the child element of the first parent div, but it doesn't select the `img` and the first `p` of the third wrapper. I figured you need some kind of array for this and apply a class to all of them, but how can I achieve this (with preferably jQuery)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're close, what you need is to go through the elements that have the `.wrapper` class and append the `noMargin` class to their first children i.e

```
$('.wrapper').each(function() { 
    $(this).children(":first").addClass("noMargin");
});
```

Comment: Glad to help! :)

Comment: This works but no need to use `each`. See the other answer or just `$('.wrapper :first-child').addClass('noMargin');`

Answer (score 2):

you can use following sample it is working fine

```
$('.wrapper :nth-child(1)').addClass("noMargin");
```

or another syntax

```
$('.wrapper :first-child').addClass('noMargin');
```

Comment: Alternative syntax: `$('.wrapper :first-child').addClass('noMargin');`

Comment: thanks @Jeto for your alternative answer can I add it to my answer?

Answer (score 0):

While I completely understand that the OP wanted a solution using jQuery, I'll post a native JavaScript solution here.

Select all elements with a specific class then loop through each element and get the first child. If a first child exists, do anything you want, in this case, add a specific class.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    var wrappers = document.getElementsByClassName("wrapper");
    for (var i = 0; i < wrappers.length; i++) {
        var firstChild = wrappers[i].children[0];
        if (firstChild) {
            firstChild.classList.add("hidden");
        }
    }
});
```

```css
.hidden {
   display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <p>Select this paragraph</p>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/300" title="Select this image">
  <p>Don't select this</p>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <p>Select this paragraph</p>
  <p>Don't select this paragraph</p>
</div>
```